# How do I re-bind an event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery code that starts the listener that highlights the DOM elements.

I click a button and I start the listener event. ex: highlight : function()

When I click something in the webpage, I stop the listener.

Now, when I click the button again, I want to restart the listener event.

```
highlight : function()
    {
        if(isHighlighting){
            isHighlighting = false;
            $(document).unbind("mousemove", highlighter);
            return false;
        }

        $(document).bind("mousemove", highlighter);
        isHighlighting = true;
    },
```

I also have the code that catches the onclick event, and stops the DOM element highlighter

```
function highlighter(e) {
    var cur, overlay = $("#overlayhighlightclosetaffair"),
    no = [document.body, document.documentElement, document];
    if (e.target === cur) {
        return;
    }

    if (~no.indexOf(e.target)) {
        cur = null;
        overlay.hide();
        return;
    }

    var target = $(e.target),
    offset = target.offset(),
    width = target.outerWidth(),
    height = target.outerHeight();
    cur = e.target;
    overlay.css({
        top: offset.top,
        left: offset.left,
        width: width,
        height: height
    }).show();

    $(document).click(
        function() {
            if(isHighlighting){
                isHighlighting = false;
                $(document).unbind("mousemove", highlighter);
                console.log('click');
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you need to rephrase or clarify as you seem to understand how to bind/unbind and it is not clear where you have need.

Comment: I understand how to bind/unbind, but the question is: if i bind, then unbind,why i cand bind again ?

Comment: is this a typo?: `if (~no.indexOf(e.target)) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to unbind the event, and can simplify your logic.

This is not a fully functional example, but it should be a good starting point.  I suggest structuring the code so that `isHighlighting` is not global.

```
function highlightElement(e) {
    if(isHighlighting) {
        /* this is where you put the code to highlight e.target */
    }
}

/* call this one time */
$(document).click(
    function(e) {
        /* this will be true if we clicked the button, false if we clicked anything else */
        isHighlighting = e.target === highlightButtonNode;
    }
});

/* also call this once */
$(document).bind("mousemove", highlightElement);
```

Here is an alternative solution using binding and unbinding. I do not recommend this approach, but this is a much better way the handle unbinding and rebinding.  Forgetting to set `isHighlight = false`.  Is a much less serious bug than forgetting to unbind the event.  It would result in a memory leak and multiple calls to an event handler is more likely to have worse side effects.

```
/* call this one time */
$(document).click(
    function(e) {
        /* this will be true if we clicked the button, false if we clicked anything else */
        if(e.target === highlightButtonNode) {
            $(document).bind("mousemove", highlightElement);
        } else {
            $(document).unbind("mousemove", highlightElement);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont understand something. I have 2 functions, 1st highlight, 2nd highlighter; from 1st i call 2nd and in the 2nd i have a listener for the click event; on document.click, the isHighlighting is always true, because i set it to be true and here is where i unbind the event; if i undind, how do i re bind ? and can i aproach this using live instead of bind ?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian, I do not understand your comment or the approach you are using to solve the problem.  You are using some kind of circular logic that does not make sense.  You misunderstood the point of my answer, you only need to bind the event once, and never need to unbind.  I have added a more complete example.  Even though I recommend against it, I have also added an example of a better approach to rebinding.